# What's the appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask 'coding convention'-esque questions?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I have questions on proper/generally proffered programming conventions (i.e. code that works the same, but uses different features, styles, functions, etc.). I have wanted to post them here, but for some reason I feel like it isn't the proper place.

So, in what Stack Exchange site should I post such questions?

For example:

> Should I use std::ifstream::good() or std::ifstream::operator bool()?

Comment: Those two are not equivalent :)

Comment: None of the sites want opinion-based questions. It is often quite possible to ask the question in a way that does not require an opinion but is based on facts. In this particular case you'd ask "What is the difference between good() and operator bool() to test if a stream is usable?"  Also the way to find out that this question is likely to be already asked, you'd Google "c++ difference between good() and operator bool" and it takes you straight to the SO post that answer it.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Maybe I should've checked before posting :) Sorry for the bad example, but I hope you get what I mean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably no Stack Exchange sites would welcome such a question as completely opinions based. Definitely not Stack Overflow.

[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) may be a place to get advice on getting measurably better ways to write a particular working piece of code. I don’t think a question about  picking between equally reasonable ways to write the same code would be on-topic there either.